# How can I import a python module whose name is a uid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonpath

For some reason, I had to change a module name from `A.py` to `0880ceae-8a46-11eb-bcf6-38f9d349be8e.py`. `0880ceae-8a46-11eb-bcf6-38f9d349be8e.py` is a uid generated by `uuid.uuid1()`.

After my change, I try to  import a `class B` from the `py` file by the following two ways, both do not work out.

First solution is to import directly

```
from 0880ceae-8a46-11eb-bcf6-38f9d349be8e import B
```

It has an error `SyntaxError: invalid token`

Second solution is to define a variable before import

```
uid = '0880ceae-8a46-11eb-bcf6-38f9d349be8e'
from uid import Model_API
```

And it has en error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uid'`

Anyone has a good idea? Thanks.

Comment: In Python, valid identifiers cannot contain dashes or start with numbers, and module names are identifiers. Does the filename *have* to be that specific value or can you add a prefix and change the dashes, say to `A_0880ceae_8a46_11eb_bcf6_38f9d349be8e.py`?

Comment: If you really insist on using non-standard names you might be able to construct something with [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible solution to your problem tested using python3:

```py
# Modern approach
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module(".", "0880ceae-8a46-11eb-bcf6-38f9d349be8e")
module.hello()

# Deprecated way
module = __import__("0880ceae-8a46-11eb-bcf6-38f9d349be8e")
module.hello()
```

Both of the above methods are tested and works.

Here are the rules to keep in mind:

- Check your filename should end with `.py` extension, `.py.py` will cause ModuleNotFoundError.
- Make sure to not include `.py` extension while using in `importlib` module.

Comment: The error is because you have mixture of spaces and tabs in the document, Go ahead and convert all tabs to spaces in your document, it will fix it. Most of the ide supports converting tabs to spaces.

Comment: Have you treid it as the question did, that is, rename the `py` file to `uid.py`? Seems it will also have the problem `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uid'`